# Special characters in PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, character

This form accepts special characters (é,à,ç,è,...) in every place EXCEPT "naam" and "voornaam", which means Name and First Name. When people with a special character in their name would fill in the fields I would not receive the message, which is very weird since it works in every field except "naam" and "voornaam". Any help please?

```
<?php
        
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            
            $onderwerp = "Iemand gebruikte het contactformulier"; 
            
            $emailadres = ( trim($_POST['email']) == "" ) ? 'contact@xxx.be' : $_POST['email']; // E-mailadres van de afzender
            $naar = 'xxx@outlook.be'; // E-mailadres van de ontvanger
            
            $afzendernaam = explode('@',$emailadres);
            $afzendernaam = $_POST['naam'] . ' ' . $_POST['voornaam'];
            
            $header = "From: ".$afzendernaam." <".$emailadres.">\r\n"; 
            $header .= "Reply-To: ".$emailadres." \r\n";
            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
            $header .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
            $header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\r\n";
            $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP / ".phpversion()."\r\n";
            
            
            $mail = 'Naam: '.$_POST['naam'].'
                    Voornaam: '.$_POST['voornaam'].'
                    Adres: '.$_POST['straat'].'
                    Postcode: '.$_POST['postcode'].'
                    Telefoon: '.$_POST['telefoon'].'
                    E-mail: '.$_POST['email'].'
                    Bericht: '.$_POST['bericht'].'';
                    
            mail($naar, $onderwerp, $mail,$header);
            echo "Het formulier is succesvol verzonden, u kan nu verder gaan op de website.";
            
        }
        else
        {
?>
<div id="wrapper">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <p class="underline">Of via ons online contactformulier:</p>
    <br>
    <label>Uw naam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="naam">
    <br>
    <label>Uw voornaam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="voornaam">
    <br>
    <label>Uw straat en huisnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="straat">
    <br>
    <label>Uw postcode:</label>
    <input type="number" name="postcode">
    <br>
    <label>Uw telefoonnummer:</label>
    <input type="number" name="telefoon">
    <br>
    <label>Uw e-mailadres:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <br>
    <label>Uw bericht:</label>
    <textarea rows="6" cols="25" name="bericht"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden" class="submit">
  </form>
</div>
<?php
        
        }
?>
```

Comment: @op When you say that the form doesn't accept those characters in those fields, what do you mean? This acceptance is generally handled duing input validation of which you hardly do any. Do some individual input validation on each field and it will be easier for you to find the answer to your question. Start by checking if each individual field is set, then check if it's empty, then check if it corresponds to a certain regex perhaps. Print stuff while doing this and you'll be able to diagnose your problem...

Comment: @fast-reflexes Well when someone fills in those fields and the persons name is Jòhn Doè, I will not get the form by mail. But when you fill in your street name or any other field with special characters there is no problem. It is only with "naam" and "voornaam" that  it will not work.

Also, for the user there is no problem since for him it will send, and he will get the success message on the website. But I will never recieve the form by mail. Very weird.

Comment: take a look here http://www.atto.nl/utf8/ And just for the record, you should use "U kunt nu ..." insteand of "U kan ".